# How can I keep a VNC session running when not connected to it?

Tags: python, vnc, selenium-webdriver

I'm running a scraping bot with selenium, and to get results as stable as possible I'm running a chrome instance from a VNC desktop and then attaching selenium to it ; it's not headless and allows me to diagnose anything going wrong easily.

Of course I'd like my VNC desktop to keep running even when I'm not connected to it. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: The VNC server will continue to run whenever anything is connected to it or not. You can have many different connections to the server (including zero).

Comment: Ah, nice. Thanks !

Comment: @Milliways It seems that while it keeps running, it does not render a display. pyautogui does not have access to it, at least.